# Почему работает транзакция в другой транзакции в Spring?

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть сервис метод

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public ProductDto fullyCreateProduct(FullyProductDto p) {
        VendorDto v = vendorService.createVendor(p.getVendor());
        CategoryDto c = categoryService.createCategory(p.getCategory());
        return createProduct(
                productMapper.toDtoFromOtherDto(p, v, c));
    }
```

в нем есть 2 других сервис метода, которые успешно отрабатывают.

Почему?
Как мне известно, методы внутри других транзакций не должны срабатывать, так как это прокси классы и у них уже не будет аннотаций @Transactional.

Comment: почему не будут? просто не будет работать аннотации над методом и все
Какую ошибку вы ожидаете увидеть?

Comment: @Санаев Ошибку, что не срабатывает транзакция, так как над классами у меня стоит Transactional(readonly = true).